# How to do a view hierarchy dump in android app

Tags: android, hierarchy

I want to profile my ui - it falls on stackoverflow for the onDraw method

I've been told its because my ui has too many layers

I wanted to do a view hierarchy dump to see how deep my layers are

but when i try to load the hierarchyviewer I get this error:

```
Error obtaining UI hierarchy
Error while obtaining UI hierarchy XML file: com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Remote object doesn't exist!
```

how do i fix it?

Comment: I think it is a known bug, but they do not have a solution for that. maybe you could provide more information to the issue it it can be fixed soon. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57024

Comment: Is there anything i can do to analyze my ui without this tool ?

Answer (score 0):

If we can't fix this problem yet since it's a known problem,

we can try the [monkey talk](https://www.gorillalogic.com/monkeytalk/features-benefits).

It provides a view hierarchy with its own mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Genymotion emulator instead until this is fixed.  the uiautomatorviewer has no issues with it from my experience.